# Commutation relation of continuous field operators taken at equal position

Tags: quantum-field-theory

The commutation relation for a continuous bosonic field theory is 
\begin{equation}
[\psi(x),\psi^\dagger(y)]=\delta(x-y)
\end{equation}
What becomes of this relation when $x=y$ ? I.e, is there a simple relation between $\psi^\dagger  (x)\psi(x)$ and $\psi(x)\psi^\dagger (x)$ ?

Comment: Physicists (sometimes including me) have a habit of using not-yet-fully-defined expressions for the sake of brevity, and then putting bandages on the resulting problems when they arise. The case shown in your question is a classic example of this. Are you asking what kinds of bandages are typically used in this case? Or are you asking how we can properly define things in the first place? (We can, and an answer to this latter question would probably be more productive in the long run, but both questions are valid.)

Comment: Ideally, I would like to have both questions answered but as you said there is probably more benefit in the long run to know what the proper definition of things is.

Comment: Are you familiar with lattice QFT? This is a widely-applicable approach for properly defining a QFT in the first place, so that no bandages are ever needed. The idea is simple: just replace continuous $D$-dimensional space with a discrete lattice. Then the commutation relation is $[\psi(x),\psi^\dagger(y)]=a^{-D}\delta_{x,y}$ where $a$ is the lattice spacing. When $x=y$, this becomes $\psi(x)\psi^\dagger(x)-\psi^\dagger(x)\psi(x)=a^{-D}$. The details can get messy, and the lattice is clearly artificial, but it works. Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: I understand that problems can be avoided by going to discrete lattice but my question is precisely about the continuous case. If you take the limit $a \to 0$ in your expression, the commutator at equal position is ill-defined, isn't it?

Comment: Right. In other words, starting with a discrete lattice, we can't take the continuum limit of the commutation relation, because then $\psi(x)$ is not defined as an operator on a Hilbert space. One way to fix this in continuous space is to write the relation as $[\psi(f),\psi^\dagger(g)]=\int dx\ f(x) g^*(x)$ where $f$ and $g$ are functions (so the field operators are parameterized by functions instead of by points), but then $\psi(x)$ is still undefined, so the Hamiltonian is still undefined. Using a discrete lattice might not be the only way to fix this, but it might be the easiest way.